# How to merge multiple rows of single column in SQL Server 2005?

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2005

I get a output as shown in below table from my query as

[image]

Now I need my output should something like below table

[image]

It will merge the common fields of multiple rows into one cell.

How can I write a query to do this?

Answer (score 1):

It is not exactly clear what you are trying to do but this will place the items from the code and value columns into a single row:

```
select distinct id,
  stuff((select ', ' + code
        from yourtable t2
        where t1.id = t2.id
        for XML path('')),1,1,'')  code,
  stuff((select ', ' + cast(value as varchar(10))
        from yourtable t2
        where t1.id = t2.id
        for XML path('')),1,1,'')  value
from yourtable t1
```

See [SQL Fiddle with Demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/c0bbc/9)

Answer (score 1):

This type of formatting is normally better suited to doing in the presentation layer or reporting tool, but here is one way to do something similar in T-SQL:

```
select
    case when rownumber = 1 then cast(id as varchar(11)) else '' end as id
  , code
  , value
from (
  select
      *
    , id as idsort
    , row_number() over (partition by id order by code) as rownumber
  from yourtable
) as a
order by idsort, rownumber
```

Again, this wouldn't display like an html table or anything, nor have all kinds of formatting and alignment options.

Thanks to @bluefeet for setting up [the fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/c0bbc/20).